# How to copy and paste in Minecraft on Linux/Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, ubuntu

Can someone please explain how to do this? I have tried looking at Mac commands, but haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Try getting your 'text' and doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy (highlight it) and in-game do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

There must be several folks having a hard time figuring this out, as there is a multiple-page thread on this subject over on MinecraftForum.net, as well.

[How the heck do you copy and paste in Minecraft?](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/discussion/167012-how-the-heck-do-you-copy-and-paste-in-minecraft)

Basically-

- Select All: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>
- Copy selected text: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>
- Paste copied text: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>